# Wordpress - Robotx.txt allows admin login?

Tags: wordpress, seo, robots.txt

First, i've searched by robots.txt for Wordpress, but, no one told me where is this file. So, I read that the robots.txt in Wordpress is virtual.

Ok, no problem. But, where i find this to edit? My Wordpress is allowing the **/author/admin** and i don't want this.

In dashboard, the only option for something like this is too general, like "block search engine to find this website" (something like this).

Anyone knows a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your own robots.txt file and upload it to website root directory.

Follow the following steps to create and upload into root folder:

1. Open notepad
2. Add the following text into this file, remember add also your website sitemap path

   ```
   sitemap: http://www.yoursite.com/sitemap.xml 
   User-agent: * 
   Disallow: /cgi-bin/ 
   Disallow: /wp-admin/ 
   Disallow: /wp-includes/ 
   Disallow: /wp-content/ 
   Disallow: /archives/ 
   disallow: /*?* 
   Disallow: *?replytocom 
   Disallow: /wp-* 
   Disallow: /author 
   Disallow: /comments/feed/ 
   User-agent: Mediapartners-Google* 
   Allow: / 
   User-agent: Googlebot-Image 
   Allow: /wp-content/uploads/ 
   Allow: / 
   User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile 
   Allow: /
   ```
3. Save as robots.txt
4. Open your website root directory
5. Copy and paste this file into root directory

   In that way your robots.txt file will be updated and will be shown in directory.
6. Finally go to webmaster account in robots.txt section. You can test that file and you can submit that file too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not familiar with robots.txt and you're ok to install a good plugin you can try *WP SEO by Yoast* that include a tool for generate a custom robots.txt and much more. Here is the link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You must create your own robots.txt file in root directory which will override the virtual file or use a plugin for that.

Comment: Hum, ok. But where i place this file? Root? Themes?

Comment: Edit: yeah it's root.

Answer (score 0):

There's an undocumented robots_txt hook which you can use to customize the virtual robots.txt file. It takes two parameters: the full content of the robots.txt file that WordPress generated, and a boolean value showing whether the site is "public" (open to search engines) or not.

You can add your own filter to this hook and add that URL to the virtual robots.txt with code like this in a plugin or your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'robots_txt', 'my_robots_txt_filter' );
function my_robots_txt_filter( $robots_txt, $public ) {
    $robots_txt .= "\nDisallow: /author/admin";
    return $robots_txt;
}
```